# Change label for custom field on WooCommerce product

Tags: php, woocommerce

Not sure why there wasn't already an answer to this as I thought it would be a pretty common requirement.  I have an integration that automatically creates custom fields so I can only modify the label after the fact.  Note that this is a custom field, not a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
function woocommerce_custom_fields_display()
{
    global $post;
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    $custom_fields_woocommerce_title = $product->get_meta('manufacturers_part_number');
    if ($custom_fields_woocommerce_title) {
        printf(
            '<div><label>Manufacturer Number: </label>%s</div>',
            esc_html($custom_fields_woocommerce_title)
            );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'woocommerce_custom_fields_display');
```